# Is document.getElementById a method that can be chained?

Tags: javascript, chaining, module-pattern

If I have this module pattern:

```
var MODULE = (function(window){
    var myPublicStuff = {};

    myPublicStuff.myPublicMethod = function(e){
        return e;
    };
    return myPublicStuff;

})(window);  //edit:  forgot to put I have this
```

This works: (edited for clarity)

```
v = document.getElementById('some-element'); //works as expected
MODULE.myPublicMethod(v);  //works.
```

But this does not work,

```
MODULE.myPublicMethod().document.getElementById('some-element');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('some-element').MODULE.myPublicMethod().
```

I thought that if the preceding member in the jail returned a value, you could chain it to the next link up?  That does not work here, but I do not know why.

Edit:  Thanks for all the answers.  All I'm trying to do is get the element and have that method print it back out *via chaining*.  That's all.  if I put in 'btnPrint' I want it to give me `<button type="button" id="btnPrint" class="btn">...</button>`  If I do getElementById at the console, that is what I get if I use a variable for my module first (which makes sense.)  I only wanted to do the same thing with a chained method.

Edit:  For completeness this is What Travis put on JSFiddle (thanks):

```
<button type="button" id="btnPrint" class="btn">...</button>

Element.prototype.myPublicMethod = function(){
 //in the prototype scheme that JavaScript uses,
 //the current instance of the Element is *this*,
 //so returning this will return the current Element
 //that we started with.
 return this;

}

console.log(document.getElementById("btnPrint").myPublicMethod());
```

I agree.  This looks bad unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Doesn't myPublicMethod() return an undefined if called without any input params?

Comment: Yes.  That is why I want to call the getElementById function.

Comment: `MODULE.myPublicMethod().document.getElementById(`…`)` would only work if `MODULE.myPublicMethod` returned an object that has a `document` property, which in turn has a `getElementById` property. `document`, however, is a global property on `window`, so you can’t just use it as a property of something else.

Comment: Your example that doesn't work isn't chaining.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of `document.getElementById('some-element')` as an argument to `myPublicMethod()` (i.e., `e`)? The answers so far are assuming that is not the case, except for Bergi's first couple lines.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes.  That is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is document.getElementById a method that can be chained?

Yes. It returns an Element (or undefined if there is no match). The Element exposes a generic set of functions, and if the element is a specific type (for example a form) then it may also have a specific set of functions exposed.

Read more on the generic Element type at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

> I want to do this:
>
> ```
> v = document.getElementById('some-element'); //works as expected
> MODULE.myPublicMethod(v);
> ```

Here, `v` is straightforward, right? It just gets the element with `id="some-element"`. Okay, from there you pass it into the `myPublicMethod(v)`. When you do that, all you are doing is calling a function that returns the same value that is passed in. And nothing else, there is no assignment or storing taking place in the code you show above.

What you *could* have done here, if you wanted to take advantage of the chaining setup, would be to then access the `v` element from the returned value like this:

```
v = document.getElementById('some-element');
var vId = MODULE.myPublicMethod(v).id;
console.log(vId);// this will log "some-element" to the console
```

> But this does not work,
>
> ```
>  MODULE.myPublicMethod().document.getElementById('some-element');
> ```

So above I explained that you are "calling a function that returns the same value that is passed in", remember that myPublicMethod just has `return e;` in it? Well that means that you are using `undefined` as the result since nothing was passed in using this line of code. In other words, your code above can be examined as `undefined.document.getElementById('some-element')` which is hopefully clearly problematic.

> if I put in 'btnPrint' I want it to give me `<button type="button" id="btnPrint" class="btn">...</button>`

For example, your code as written would accomplish this as such:

```js
var MODULE = (function(window){
    var myPublicStuff = {};

    myPublicStuff.myPublicMethod = function(e){
        return e;
    };
    return myPublicStuff;
})(window);

console.log(MODULE.myPublicMethod(document.getElementById('btnPrint')));
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnPrint" class="btn">...</button>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it get the 'some-element' before it calls myPublicMethod()?  I thought that's the way chaining worked.  Edit:  I guess I got it backwards.

Comment: Ahh, yeah that isn't how it works. Chaining goes from left to right. So first, you get `MODULE` which is an object containing `myPublicMethod`. Second, you then access that object using `.myPublicMethod()` (because it is available on the module object) which calls a function and in this case returns `undefined`. Third, you then access `undefined` using `.document`, which is where the problem arises, as `undefined` does not have a property document.

Comment: How come it doesn't work when you do document.getElementById('element').MODULE.myPublicMethod(e); (or without the e, same result).  It returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myPublicMethod' of undefined

Comment: So that wont work because the `Element` returned by `document.getElementById` doesn't actually contain `MODULE`. `MODULE` is a global object here. If you want to get the element into the module, then chaining it in isn't really an option. It is *possible* to hook into the `Element` prototype and add your method there, but that is rather frowned upon for several reasons, mostly that it can cause problems for other libraries and have unintended consequences. What you can do though is just pass in your element using `MODULE.myPublicMethod(document.getElementById('element'))` and that will work.

Comment: I know that overall Stack Overflow asks for minimal examples and that is probably what you have here. However, sometimes this leads to the actual idea being a trimmed a little too far. Can you explain what you were hoping to use the result of this chain for after you have the element?

Comment: honestly I just want to see the function return what I sent it.  Nothing more.  I have other functions and modules, etc., but here I only wanted to test chaining to understand it.

Comment: @johnny - Okay. So is it clear then at this point? If you pass in the element as a parameter (i.e. `MODULE.myPublicMethod(document.getElementById('element'))`) and your `myPublicMethod` function returns the value passed in (`return e;`) then you can use the result from the `myPublicMethod` using the dot notation (chaining) after the call.

Comment: Yes.  Your example here is clear.  I was able to make that work originally.  I can't do what I wanted which was to not put the element in like you have.  I cannot do it like I wanted to because of the undefined, which I understand.  I thought maybe I was just doing it wrong.  Whether I start with document.get.... or MODULE.myPublicMethod...neither of them has access to the other.  I thought maybe the document.get...would because my IIFE was global.  And I had passed in window.

Comment: @johnny - Glad that is clear. When you were thinking that the global object would overlap with the Element prototype, perhaps that was because you passed in Window? That isn't really how it works. This is how you would do that: https://jsfiddle.net/6n6mb4v1/ .... but keep in mind, while that demo demonstrates how to do that, it is generally bad practice to modify large system definitions such as `Element`.

Comment: Thanks.  When I see it now, that does not look like a good thing, but I am glad to know how and why.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the `v` variable, you need to use

```
MODULE.myPublicMethod(document.getElementById('some-element'));
```

`document` is a global property (of the `window` object), you'd need to have returned that from `myPublicMethod()` to chain off it. Given that it is the identity function, you can even do something like

```
MODULE.myPublicMethod(document).getElementById('some-element');
MODULE.myPublicMethod(window).document.getElementById('some-‌​element');
```

Comment: Bergi I tried the second one.  I passed in the window object in the IIFE.  I forgot to put that in my original.  Edit:  The first one is what I didn't want to have to do.

Comment: Putting `window` in the IIFE doesn't change anything. Yes, you can chain off `window`, but you'd use `MODULE.myPublicMethod(window).document.getElementById('some-element');` then - your method returns its argument, not always `window`. And I still don't get what you "*don't want to have to do*" - given your script doesn't currently do any real work, you could completely omit it. So what's the purpose of your module?

Comment: Bergi, I have existing objects that I'd like to redo using better patterns.  This is the first attempt at understanding the basics.  I've read lots of things, but it is no substitute for actually doing it, so that's where I am.

Comment: We cannot recommend a specific pattern without knowing more about your objects. You might want to ask a new question at [codereview.SE] with your real, current code that is to be improved (or redone). But your context-lacking basic question "can I chain something instead of passing it as an argument" can only be answered with "No".

Answer (score 1):

You can return the `document` from your function if no argument passed:

```
var MODULE = (function(window){
    var myPublicStuff = {};

    myPublicStuff.myPublicMethod = function(e){
        return e || document;
    };
    return myPublicStuff;

})();

var text = MODULE.myPublicMethod().getElementById('element').innerHTML;

console.log(text);
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/duhimetixe/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: please share your reasoning with the down-vote, thus everyone can benefit from learning what's wrong here and a better way of doing this

Comment: Didn’t downvote, but I assume it’s because this solution is too specific to `document`. What if the OP wanted a solution not only for `document`, but also for, say, `Date`? Of course this is just another assumption, because the question itself isn’t really all that clear…

Comment: @Xufox You might be right. I just assumed from OP's code that his primary goal was DOM manipulation, hence returned the `document`. But your comment (*upvoted*) about the `window` was a great complement in case he needs smth else from the global space